# Regex for matching specific syntax with spaces

Tags: regex

What would be a regular expression for accepting exactly a given content, even if it has spaces?

For example, for `"Agatha Christie"`, I wouldn't like *"Agatha"* to match it or *"Christie"* to match it, but the exact expression *"Agatha Christie"*.

Thank you!

Comment: /Agatha Christie/ - but you don't need regex for an exact string match. What are you_really_ trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make a database query.

Comment: ummmmm... what's wrong with just `"Agatha Christie"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is a very powerful tool for finding strings that match a particular specification. The simplest type of specification is "find exactly this string". And in regex, that is done by giving exactly this string as the expression.

So the expression that matches `Agatha Christie` exactly (including spaces and capitalization) is

```
/Agatha Christie/
```

If you want to be case insensitive you could add

```
/agatha christie/i
```

If you don't care whether there zero or 100 spaces,

```
/agatha[ ]*christie/i
```

etc.

If you need "Agatha Christie" as the entire string (nothing before and after) you can use

```
/^Agatha Christie$/
```

the "anchors" `^` for beginning, and `$` for end of string, ensure that no other characters can be present.

Comment: Look, if I had /Agatha/ as the filter for a search (for example) in a database, if "Agatha Christie" was in the database, would /Agatha/ match "Agatha Christie"? What I need is that /Agatha/ matches only "Agatha" and if there's "Agatha Christie" on the database, that only exactly /Agatha Christie/ matches.

Comment: Then you need to specify the beginning and end of the string with `/^Agatha Christie$/`  . The `^` signifies "start of string" and `$` means "end of string" (just like the keys you use to navigate in `vim`). With those "anchors" you can only match "this and only this and nothing else before or after". Does that help?

Comment: It helps a lot!Thank you! So let me see if I understood:If I have a variable called name that could be any string with spaces or not, and it was like /^name$/ , if I had "Agatha Christie" on the database, I would only find "Agatha Christie" if name=Agatha Christie , right? And if name=Agatha, I wouldn't find "Agatha Christie" on the database, right?

Comment: Assuming that the variable `name` expands correctly, yes. I don't know what language you are using to construct your regex string which is why I am hesitating a little bit. But assuming you can construct a string like above, then it should work. Easy enough to test, I think.

Comment: Yes!Thank you! As u said above, is that the correct one for case insensitive: /^name$/i

Answer (score 1):

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ -- for your experiments.

And the answer is:

```
/Agatha Christie/
```

if you have unpredictable amount of spaces between words:

```
/Agatha[ ]+Christie/
```

if NOT ONLY spaces:

```
/Agatha[/S]+Christie/
```

*UPDATE:*

**Q:** if "Agatha Christie" was in the database, would /Agatha/ match "Agatha Christie"?

**A:** Yes

**Q:** What I need is that /Agatha/ matches only "Agatha" and if there's "Agatha Christie" on the database, that only exactly /Agatha Christie/ matches.

**A:** If the data field consist just one therm, `/Agatha$/` will match only "Agatha", not an "Agatha Christie" and `/Agatha Christie$/` will match only "Agatha Christie", where `$` have meaning "end of the string".

Comment: Look, if I had /Agatha/ as the filter for a search (for example) in a database, if "Agatha Christie" was in the database, would /Agatha/ match "Agatha Christie"? What I need is that /Agatha/ matches only "Agatha" and if there's "Agatha Christie" on the database, that only exactly /Agatha Christie/ matches.